# Return value from CoreData with entity.attribute?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am new to swift and have been having trouble working with CoreData, I'm looking for a way to simplify fetching and writing to values, specifically being able to write them with something similar to:

```
entity.attribute = variable
```

and retrieve them with something similar to:

```
variable = entity.attribute
```

I have an entity called 'Studio' with an attribute called 'name' (string).
I've created an NSManagedObject Subclass (Studio.swift) and have updated the class to 'testapp.Studio'.

In my example code below the IBAction saveData will write studioBox.text into CoreData, however the IBAction update is throwing some errors.

```
var Studio = getStudioData()
```

> Pattern Variable Binding Cannot Appear in an Expression

```
nameLabel.text = Studio.name
```

> 'Studio.Type' does not have a member named 'name'

and finally in the getStudioData function:

```
return studio
```

> 'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'Studio'

Below is my full code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var studioBox: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func saveData(sender: AnyObject) {
    var info: String = studioBox.text!
    var Studio = dbconnect()
    Studio.name = info as String
}
@IBAction func Update(sender: AnyObject) {
    var info: String =
    var Studio = getStudioData()
    nameLabel.text = Studio.name
}


func getStudioData() -> Studio {
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Studio")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let result = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    let studio = result
    return studio

}

func dbconnect () -> Studio {
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Studio", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let studio = Studio(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    return studio
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the fetch request returns an array of objects. So if you want to return one `Studio` you should return one object of this array (e.g. the first one). Don't forget to cast your fetch result as the right type array.

```
let result = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [Studio]
// check if result.count > 0
return result[0]
```

This explains the first and third errors. The second one seems to be caused by the fact that with the capitalized `Studio` you are referring to the class, not an instance, i.e. a managed object. While it is "legal" to use variable names with capitalized first letters, it is bad practice because it makes your code less readable. Stick with names like `Studio` for class names, and `studio` for variable names.

```
nameLabel.text = studio.name
```

Comment: This solves the errors, thank you.  But it returns an unexpected result (at least not what I'd expected)

When I load a value into studio.name it persists properly, but if I exit and reload the app and input a different value into studio.name the action 'update' cycles the label between the first and second value I entered.

If the name attribute is declared as a string why does it appear to be behaving as an array?

Comment: Your question is not clear, and I think too complex to be answered via comments. It is actually a different question. You should accept the above answer by ticking the checkmark and start a new SOF question including the code to your specific unexpected behavior.